# Where can I find the xsi schema for namespace = http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format

Tags: xml, namespaces, xsl-fo

I am working with `xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"` . I am trying to find the `xsd` or `dtd` file for this namespace so I can work easier using my **IDE**.

How do I find the schema for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two links that I have looked at in the past, besides the W3C documentation. I hope these help.

[Schema Central](http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/fo11/ns-fo.html)

[OxygenXml](http://www.oxygenxml.com/samples/xml-schema-documentation/XSL20Schema/xsl_2_0_schema.html)

Comment: Thanks. But how can I download it to make it usable for the ide?

Comment: I believe you can download it from W3.org. [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/XMLSchema.xsd) or [link](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xmlgraphics/fop/trunk/src/foschema/fop.xsd)

Comment: The links from @JasonMontgomery no longer work. Eventually found this new working link: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xmlgraphics/fop/trunk/fop/src/foschema/fop.xsd?view=co As mentioned here: https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/fo.html

Answer (score 0):

The **focheck** project (https://github.com/antennahouse/focheck) includes a W3C XML Schema for XSL-FO (plus Antenna House extensions).

The XSD is translated from the Relax NG schema, and the majority of the Relax NG schema is generated directly from the XML for the XSL 1.1 Recommendation itself.